# Removing contents of pasteboard at the app level

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

We are trying to control out pasteboard contents for our application.  I have seen the way to create a custom text field and remove the ability that way, but I'm inquiring to find if there is a way to do it at the app level.

I  was trying to utilize applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidenterBackground, and applicationWillTerminate.  With those I figure I can clear the pasteboard contents and then have that data safe outside the app.

My initial attempt was to emulate something I had seen from a previous solution that may no longer  work.

```
var pb = self.pasteboard()
pb.setValue("", forPasteboardType: UIPasteboardNameGeneral)
```

The error here being that the AppDelegate has no member pasteboard

Is there a way to make it work in app delegate, or am I relegated to changing all the fields in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `self.pasteboard()`, but there is `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()`.

Use that instead.

Comment: I've implemented this and done some testing.  It seems to have worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have seen the previous answers where `self.pasteboard()` returns an instance of `UIPasteboard` and now in your application it is not handled. So you just try this:

```
let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard()
pasteBoard.setValue("", forPasteboardType: UIPasteboardNameGeneral)
```

Or if you want to get the `pasteBoard` instance in all other methods then just declare a `lazy var` in your `appDelegate`:

```
lazy var pasteBoard = UIPasteboard()
```

Then use it in any methods like below:

```
self.pasteBoard.setValue("", forPasteboardType: UIPasteboardNameGeneral)
```

Comment: The first line here threw an error, but I combined your lazy var piece with the above answer and got it working.  Thanks!